# unable to mount storage while installing new ROM - Nexus 5

Tags: rooting, 6.0-marshmallow, nexus-5, twrp, mount

i have nexus 5 rooted, its version was 4.4 i tried to upgrade it to 6.0 so i download the ROM (image-hammerhead-mob30y) from developers.google.com and i copy the image to the phone by adb push command and when i try to install the image i get the error unable to mount storage. however i cant wipe internal storage or dalvik cache from the wipe section in TWRP. also every-time i try to get root access to the shell using 'su' command i get the error **/sbin/sh: su: not found**

so what can i do to install the image? if the issue with the image what did you recommenced?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't install factory images in custom recoveries, let alone "flashing" them like regular custom ROMs.

[XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/general/tutorial-how-to-flash-factory-image-t2513701) has you covered for simple stuff like this. Excerpt taken and simplified below:

> Install adb and fastboot drivers.
>
> Download the latest factory images
>
> Extract the archive you downloaded.
>
> Unlock your bootloader (In case you haven't already)
>
> Power off your phone.
>
> Boot it in fastboot by pressing and holding Power Button + Volume Down at the same time.
>
> Connect your phone to your PC through your USB cable.
>
> Execute the flash-all.bat script (for Windows) or flash-all.sh(for MAC and LINUX) in the folder where you extracted the factory images.
>
> Wait for everything to flash.
>
> After everything finished, select "Recovery" using the volume buttons.
>
> When a small dead Android appears, press Power Button + Volume UP.
>
> Select "Wipe data/factory data reset"
>
> Reboot.